# How to create an editable list of items in Qt Designer?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt Designer to create a Qt 5.4 GUI application (actually, I'm using Qt Creator 3.3.2 but haven't done any C++ yet; everything is in the .ui file).

I'd like to create a box containing an (empty) list of items from which the user could double click inside the box to add a new element to the list (can be single click or other, doesn't really matter).

I just can't figure out how to do this *only through the designer*. I've checked the properties of the "List Widget (Item-Based)" and "List View (Model-Based)" and there is some options in "editTriggers", but even with the default "DoubleClicked" checked, the compiled application does not allow adding a new element (or deleting...)

Any easy way to achieve this using *only* the Designer (without doing C++)?

Or is there another widget that would be better suited for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make such a widget, that can be setup completely in the designer only, you are asking a little too much.

If you start with a `List Widget` and add a bunch of empty named elements, and then make all of them editable, it will seem like you can just double click to add an element.

To make an existing element you've added in the list editable, (in the designer) double click your List Widget, then

in `Edit Widget List`, click the plus sign, followed by `Properties`.  Scroll down to `flags`, then check `Editable`.

This needs to manually be done for each item added.

The C++ to add what you are asking for is very painless.

Add a Push Button.  Rename it's `objectName` to `addItemButton`.

Then right click on it, and select `Go to slot...`.

Select `clicked()`, then click `Ok`.

Now put the following in the slot:

```
void MainWindow::on_addItemButton_clicked()
{
    QListWidgetItem * item = new QListWidgetItem("New Item");
    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
}
```

[image]

Done.

Hope that helps.